# How do I use object object1 = new object on my program?

Tags: java

I have an assignment where my program outputs a simple String using if conditions of another String, but I keep running into a problem where I cannot create a new instance(i think that is what it is called)

anyway, here is my code

```
 import java.util.Scanner;


public class EP54
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
        System.out.print("Do you want to continue? ");
        **yesNoChecker check1 = new yesNoChecker();**
        System.out.print(EP54.yesNoChecker);
    }

   public String yesNoChecker()
   {
       if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("y") ||
         in.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") ||
         in.equalsIgnoreCase("Sure") ||
         in.equalsIgnoreCase("why not"))
         System.out.println("OK");
       else if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("y") ||
         in.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") ||
         in.equalsIgnoreCase("Sure") ||
         in.equalsIgnoreCase("why not"))
         System.out.println("Terminating.");
       else
         System.out.println("Bad Input");
   }
}
```

Please help me! (bolded part is where I get error)

Can anybody give me a working version of the code so I can compare it with mine?

Comment: yesNoChecker() is a method, you can't instantiate it.

Comment: Okay I changed my code to this: http://pastie.org/2796683

Comment: On line 10, I get the error"non-static method yesNoChecker(java.util.Scanner) cannot be referenced from a static content"

Comment: I edited my code to this: http://pastie.org/2796907

Comment: I am so confused right now. Can anybody explain to me indepth?

Comment: @DSdavidDS Explain what in particular? Classes and methods are pretty well described in most Java tutorials, which are longer than fit here easily. What resources are you currently using as references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EP54
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
       System.out.print("Do you want to continue? ");
       String answer = in.next();
       yesNoChecker(answer);
   }

   public static void yesNoChecker(String in)
   {
       if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("y") ||
         in.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") ||
         in.equalsIgnoreCase("Sure") ||
         in.equalsIgnoreCase("why not"))
         System.out.println("OK");
       else if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("n") ||
         in.equalsIgnoreCase("no") ||
         in.equalsIgnoreCase("nope") ||
         in.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
         System.out.println("Terminating.");
       else
         System.out.println("Bad Input");;
   }
}
```

Got it

Answer (score 0):

`yesNoChecker()` is a function, not an object.  In this case you will want to *invoke* `yesNoChecker()` (also known as "calling the method"), rather than *instantiate* `yesNoChecker` (also known as "creating an object").  Instead, your code should look something like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class EP54
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
        System.out.print("Do you want to continue? ");
        yesNoChecker();
        System.out.print(EP54.yesNoChecker);
    }

   public String yesNoChecker()
   {
       // (omitted for brevity)
   }
}
```

You *instantiate* new objects of a class type.  For example, `Scanner` is a class that you've used here that Java provides you with.  When you say `new Scanner()`, you are creating a new instance of the `Scanner` class.

Comment: Don't forget the String return!

Comment: EP54.yesNoChecker is still the method (and not static either). I think you can remove the method call prior to system out and just change the sys out to yesNoChecker(). Btw, if this is assignment, shouldn't it be marked as homework?

Answer (score 0):

yesNoChecker is a method, not a class-you cannot instantiate it.

You can *call* it:

```
yesNoChecker();
```

However, it is defined to return a String, which it currently does not do. You may want to return the string you are now printing instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the actual input from the user/Scanner class also.

Something like:

```
String s = in.nextLine();
```

Then you compare the String s to whatever you need ("Y", "yes" etc...)

Hope this helps!

p.s. Your function does that, but consider if someone enters a digit rather than a letter or a work. It is always a good idea to validate input before using it.